# Solving $(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+a(a+1)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

I need to find an even solution and an odd solution to the ODE  $(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+a(a+1)y=0$ using a power series around $x=0$.

I suspect I should use Frobenius, but not sure how to bring it to the right form.

Comment: the solution containes the hypergeometric function

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner And can I get to that using power series?

Comment: When $a$ is an integer, the solutions are given by Legendre polynomials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).

Comment: I'm guessing you need a nontrivial solution, but $y(x)=0$ is both even and odd, and satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:
I have fixed an error pointed out
by Whyka.

$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+by
=0
$
with
$b = a(a+1)$.

When $x$ is small,
this is
$y''+by
= 0
$
which has solutions
$y
=u\sin(x\sqrt{b})+v\cos(x\sqrt{b})
$.
So,
this seems like what the solutions look like.

Proceeding mechanically,
let
$y(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n
=a_0+a_1x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_nx^n
$.
The reason for this
will appear later.

$\begin{array}\\
xy'(x)
&=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_nx^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_nx^{n}\\
&=a_1x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} na_nx^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
(1-x^2)y''(x)
&=(1-x^2)\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_nx^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_nx^{n}\\
&=2a_2+6a_3x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (n(n-1)a_n-(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2})x^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Adding these up,
and separating the terms for
$n < 2$,

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+by\\
&=2a_2+6a_3x-2a_1x+b(2a_0+6a_1x)
+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (n(n-1)a_n-(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-2na_n+ba_n)x^{n}\\
&=2(a_2+ba_0)+2x(6a_3-2a_1+6ba_1)
+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} ((n(n-1)-2n+b) a_n-(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2})x^{n}\\
&=2(a_2+ba_0)+2x(6a_3-2a_1(1-3b))
+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} ((n(n-3)+b) a_n-(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2})x^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Equating the coefficients
to zero,

$a_2+ba_0=0$
or
$a_2
=-ba_0
$;

$0
= 6a_3-2a_1+6ba_1
= 6a_3-2a_1(1-3b)
$
or
$a_3
=a_1(\frac13-b)
$;

and,
for $n \ge 2$,
$0 
=(n(n-3)+b) a_n-(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}
$
or
$a_{n+2}
=\frac{n(n-3)+b}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n
$.

From this,
we see that 
there are two independent solutions:
One with
$a_0 = 0$
(the odd solution)
and
one with 
$a_1 = 0$
(the even solution).

We also see that
if
$b=\frac13$,
the odd solution
is just
$a_1x/3$,
since all the higher
odd coefficients
are zero.

Similarly,
if $b = -n(n-3)$
for some $n$,
the even solution
is a polynomial,
since
$a_{n+2} = 0$
for the $n$ such that
$b=n(n-3)$
and all greater
even $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Comment: In the expansion of $(1-x^2)y''$, isn't there supposed to be a minus sign between the sums in line two?

Comment: And why can I choose $a_0$ and $a_1$?

Comment: @Whyka: You are right! Another silly mistake of mine. Thank. I will correct it. Upvoted.

Also, $a_0$ and $a_1$ can be any value. They are scale factors for the even and odd solutions. You can set them to 1.